# make divs responsive with div content at centre of div

Tags: html, css

hi I am new to bootstrap I am trying to achieve this effect on large screen
but with the text in div-2 at vertical centre of div.

I am trying to put Lorem ipsum text in this image at centre of div-2

[image]

but if I add a padding from top the text gets at centre on large screen but when I scale down the screen size to small or medium screens then I still have this unnecessary padding from top so I get this layout.

unnecessary padding from top in div-2 in this image

[image]

All I want is the text in div-2 to be in vertical-centre on lg devices and below the img on sm and md devices without the padding from top.
sorry if Iam not clear,your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: show your efforts..!!

Comment: I have posted a question it simply means I am done trying and need some help :)

Comment: you didn't posted any code

Comment: I wasn;t expecting a code as an answer but just the idea on how to use bootstrap classes to get the desired output,thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

Open the snippet in full screen and check

Adding `d-flex align-items-lg-center align-items-sm-top` will center align the text verticaly on large screen and will align the text to top on small screens.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-lg-6,.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
.image{
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-12 image   text-center text-lg-left">
      Image
    </div>
    <div class=" col-lg-6 col-sm-12 justify-content-center d-flex align-items-lg-center align-items-sm-top">

      lorem ipsum

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Add `text-center text-lg-left` to center image on small & medium devices but align on left only for large devices

Comment: @maheshmnj , if this answer helped u, then please accept it

Comment: ohh yeah! sure :)

Comment: hi the solution works but the image always stays fixed at the left hand side unless I add some padding or margin, How can I make the image float at center on small and md devices.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.div-2{
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:3px solid;
}
.contant{
position:absolute;
transform: translateY(-50%);
right: 0;
left: 0;
top:50%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-2">
<span class="contant">
LOREM IPSUM
LOREM IPSUM
</span>
</div>
```